# err_connection_timed_out and PHP Warning: mysqli_connect():(HY000/2002):Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

Recently, from few weeks ago I got **err_connection_timed_out** just **sometimes** while working with my website.

and i am sure, my users get this error too.
When i see at error log, there are a few of message like below

**PHP Warning:mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock**

I changed 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' for TCP connection instead of Unix socket, but no success.

My server host admin do not accept any problem at server side (like always!).

I asked them to restart Mysql, but they do not accept because it is a share server.

It is a Directadmin server and they recommend switch to Cpanel as the last chance.

Do you have any experience and solution for this problem?

**EDIT**: The main problem is **err_connection_timed_out** which i get in browser and i don't know if it relates to Mysql connection error in log file.

Answer (score 0):

Switching might have positive effects because it's differently setup.
But if it happens sometimes it is probably the MYSQL server is burping.

Lately it's normal that the services has limit per user; so you can try to enable cache (of that is possible); to see whether it's less frequent (might be some queries that is running long).

do you have any cronjobs running or other processes around the time you receive those errors?

Comment: Cache is enabled and i have cron job, but not arround the time i receive errors

Answer (score 0):

Normally this problem is caused due to MySQL server timing-out database connections is faster than the Stash connection pool can notice. This exhausts the Stash connection pool as it will keep its connections open while the MySQL side of the connections is already closed.

**Easiest solution.**
You can fix it by simply change this parameter (wait_timeout) at the Mysql config.

**More difficult but better**
Also you can close all connections in your code after you got the values. And finally you can change your connection to your database in order to reuse an existing connections.

**And last but not least**
Try a vps you got out there too many oferts, even for free. You wouldn't be able to change anything in a shared host sorry. :(